# Multiple Marionette.ItemView on same "region"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Given -

**Two Marionette App's , each one hold `ItemView` with `template` on same `region` , finally I create instance of those both `ItemView`  -**

```
<script>
 ManagerMarionette1 = new Marionette.Application();
        // region which affect ...
        ManagerMarionette1.addRegions({
            mainRegion: "#mainRegion",
        });

        // view item
        ManagerMarionette1.RegionItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: _.template('<div class="region">Marionette 1</div>'),
            onRender: function () {
                this.$('.region');
            }
        });



        ManagerMarionette2 = new Marionette.Application();
        // region which affect ...
        ManagerMarionette2.addRegions({
            mainRegion: "#mainRegion",
        });

        // view item
        ManagerMarionette2.RegionItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: _.template('<div class="region">Marionette 2</div>'),
            onRender: function () {
                this.$('.region');
            }
        });
...
MyMarionette1 = ManagerMarionette1.RegionItemView;
        myMarionette1 = new MyMarionette1();

        MyMarionette2 = ManagerMarionette2.RegionItemView;
        myMarionette2 = new MyMarionette2();

</script>
```

**The `region` tag is -**

```
<div id="mainRegion"></div>
```

**Two button for the two Marionette `ItemView` render -**

```
<button onclick="ManagerMarionette1.mainRegion.show(myMarionette1)">Show Marionette 1</button>
    <button onclick="ManagerMarionette2.mainRegion.show(myMarionette2);">Show Marionette 2</button>
```

Apparently it looks workout - each `button` render its `ItemView` but after some clicking on these `button`'s it render only in one of the button's and the other one stop rendering .

How could I manage the `Marionette` app such that it render the region OK for each button ?

**Edit:**

New version according to **@David_Sulc** suggestion - [Here](https://github.com/urielz1987/MarionetteTestUriel/blob/master/backboneMarionetteTwoItemViewOneRegionWithModules.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really bad idea: normally if you show 2 different views in the same region, the 2nd `show` call will close the currently displayed view (and sotp listening for events, etc.). But in your case, you're using 2 different marionette regions so this isn't happening and you're probably creating memory leaks each time you switch between the 2 views.

Instead, you should be using sub-modules (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#defining-sub-modules) that both display views in the main application.

Comment: Thank a lot ! Now it works , I would like you take a look on the new one (in the edited post) and tell me whether it's the good idea :)

Comment: Your use case is actually much simpler, see http://jsfiddle.net/RtBgQ/4/ And if you're interested in learning Marionette, take a look at my book there's a free preview here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf